# Seaborn FacetGrid plot two different y axis next to eachother

Tags: python, seaborn

This works, but I'm sure there's got to be a way to do this via FacetGrid. Im imagining some kind of parameter where you can access where the chart is located on the grid. Or maybe this was considered redundant and using plt.subplots is the way to access the axis of the grid.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
sns.catplot(x='not.fully.paid', y='int.rate', kind='box', data=loans, ax=ax1)
sns.catplot(x='not.fully.paid', y='fico', kind='box', data=loans, ax=ax2)
```

Even when I call this, this prints out in the display...

```
<seaborn.axisgrid.FacetGrid at 0x1a314b6c50>
```

Granted, I get my plot of the two catplots next to eachother, but an empty facetgrid below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually surpising that this code works. `sns.catplot()` is designed to plot onto a `FacetGrid` and is not meant to be used the way you are using it.

I think you should use `sns.boxplot()` directly:

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
sns.boxplot(x='not.fully.paid', y='int.rate', kind='box', data=loans, ax=ax1)
sns.boxplot(x='not.fully.paid', y='fico', kind='box', data=loans, ax=ax2)
```

If you really wanted to use `catplot` you would have to transform your dataframe so that all y-values would be in a single column, with an additional category column indicating the type of value (int.rate/fico) and then call:

```
sns.catplot(x='not.fully.paid', y='<values column>', col='<category column>', kind='box', data=loans)
```

and seaborn would automatically the correct subplots to accommodate the number of unique categories in your category column.

Comment: This does get rid of the empty FacetGrid, but is there not a way with FacetGrid to pass different plotting functions and the parameters associated with those functions more similarly to how PairGrid supports map_diag and map_upper?

Comment: No, a `FacetGrid` is designed to split your data in several categories and plot the same relationship with the same plotting function across all categories for easy comparison.

Comment: Ahh it'd be cool to be able to pass FacetGrid a list of Y values but thank you for clearing this up